# Unrecognized field Jackson YAML Reader

Tags: java, jackson

Main.java

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
            Model k = mapper.readValue(new File(PATH), Model.class);
```

Model.java

```
 public class Model {

        @JsonProperty
        private Specs details;

        private class Specs{
            @JsonProperty
            private String topic;

            @JsonProperty
            private String id;

            @JsonProperty
            private List<String> list;
        }
    }
```

**yamlfile.yaml**

```
details:
   topic: "test"
   id: "123"
   servers: [
            "test2"
            ]
```

I run **main.java** and get an exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "details" (class Model), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: src/main/config/yamlfile.yaml; line: 2, column: 3] (through reference chain: Model["details"])
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here and I cant seem to find out the problem. Why is this unrecognized?

Comment: do you have setters and getters, and i will suggest to make this class as public and static `public static class Specs`

Answer (score 1):

By default Jackson can access public fields for serialization and deserialization. If there's no public fields available then public getters/setters are used.

So: add getters/setters or add `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)` at the class level. For both classes, sure.

Comment: Thanks! But now I am getting `can only instantiate non-static inner class by using default, no-argument constructor` Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Probably because my ineer class is private. Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: `Specs` should be `public static class` or just create a new class in new file instead of inner class.